# bootstrap tabs not working from MSFT example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Could some take a quick look at my JS Fiddle.  I copied this example from a MSFT video but it doesn't work when I click on the tabs

```
<body>  
<div class="container">
   <h2>Tabs</h2>

     <!-- Tabs -->
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
     </ul> 
     <!-- Tab Content -->
     <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="active tab-pane fade in" id="tabs-first">
           <h2>First</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-second">
           <h2>Second</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

[TABS](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/15h2Lvbb/)

Comment: You need to include jQuery and BootstrapJS for Tabs to work: see the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-overview).

Comment: Thanks! It's the little things in life

Comment: No problem and you're welcome.